# Is the space of compact linear operators on a separable Banach space separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

let $K(X)$ denote the space of compact linear operators on a separable Banach space $X$ to itself. It is a known result that $K(X)$ is a closed subspace of $L(X)$, the space of linear operators on $X$ to itself, endowed with the operator norm.

Is it also known whether $K(X)$ is separable?

Comment: For a Hilbert space the compact operators form a separable space.

Comment: The answer and attached comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288228/space-of-compact-operators-defined-on-separable-hilbert-space) show that this is the case if and only if X has separable dual.

Comment: Thank you @RhysSteele. I am essentially interested in the case where either $X$ is Hilbert (which is covered in the answer below, or in the case $X=C(D)$, with compact $D$. Do you think the link you suggest would work (I do not yet have an understanding of weak-* concepts)?

Answer (score 7):

Let $X=\ell^1(\mathbb{N}).$ For any $a\in \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ the operator $$T_ax=\left (\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n\right )\delta_1$$ is compact as $T_a$ is one-dimensional. Moreover the mapping $$\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}) \ni a\longmapsto T_a \in K(X)$$ is an isometry. Hence $K(X)$ is not separable.

When $X=\mathcal{H}$ is a separable Hilbert space the finite dimensional operators are dense in $K(\mathcal{H})$ The $n$-dimensional operators form a subspace isomorphic to   $\mathcal{H}^{2n}.$ Thus the space $K(\mathcal{H})$ is separable.

Comment: Thank you, you mention the answer is affirmative when $X$ is Hilbert. Do you know if this is also true when $X = C(D)$, with compact $D \subset \mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: It is not true for $C(D)$ as the dual space is not separable. More explicitly let $T_af=f(a)\cdot 1$ for any $a\in D.$  Then $T_a$ are one dimensional and for $a\neq b$ we get  $$\|T_a-T_b\|=\sup_{f\in C(D)\,\|f\|_\infty\le 1}|f(a)-f(b)|=2$$

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. Do you know if there is any separable subset of the compact (or even of the bounded) linear operators on $C(D)$? I now understand that $K(X) \subset BL(X)$ fails to be separable if $X = C(D)$, but maybe another subset does? I am working with compact linear integral operators of the type $W \colon v \mapsto \int_D w(x,y) v(y) dy$, on $C(D)$ to $C(D)$.

Comment: The family of such operators is separable as $\|W-V\|\le \|w-v\|_{C(D\times D)}$ provided that the kernels $w(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are continuous on $D\times D.$ Are you admitting noncontinuous kernels ?

Comment: Thank you, not necessarily continuous but I can get around this. I am sorry that I am slow. If I interpret correctly you state that the following claim is true: Let $D\subset R^d$ compact, $E = C(D \times D)$, $X=C(D)$ and let $T: E \to K(X)$, with $T(w) \colon v\mapsto \int_D  w(x,y) v(y) dy$. The set $\{ T(w) \colon w \in E\} \subset K(X)$ is separable. To prove this, you use $\| T(w) \| \leq \| w \|_E$. If I understand how your proof works (and I don't yet), I will then be able prove an identical statement for $E=C(D,L^1(D))$ because I still have $\| T(w) \| \leq C \| w \|_E$ then.

Comment: The inequality $\|T(w)\|\le C\|w\|_E$ implies that if $E$ is separable, so is $\{T(w)\,:\,w\in E\}.$