# Space of compact operators defined on separable Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $K(H)$ the Banach space of all compact linear maps from $H$ into itself (with the operator norm).

Show that $K(H)$ is separable.

There is a hint that states that I should find a countable set of compact symmetric linear maps that is dense in the set of all compact symmetric linear maps.

Any hints on how to show this? Is the set of all compact symmetric linear maps dense in $K(H)$?

Alternatively, is it possible to utilize the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2367663/density-of-finite-rank-operator-in-compact-operators-on-hilbert-spaces?rq=1)?

Comment: Hint: show that the space of finite-rank operators is separable, and use that it is dense in $K(H)$

Comment: This is true whenever $X$ has a Schauder Basis $(x_n)$ and $X^*$ has a dense sequence $(x_n^*)$.  More on the hint: Try to approximate each one dimensional operator $L(u)= \langle x^*,u \rangle x,$ where $x^* \in X^*, \ x \in X$ by a suitable operator $A$ that depends on some $x_n,x_m^*$.

Now, how can you approximate a finite rank operator?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4628535/is-the-space-of-compact-linear-operators-on-a-separable-banach-space-separable and also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288228/space-of-compact-operators-defined-on-separable-hilbert-space